# Owl Carousel Events in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, owl-carousel

I am using owl-carousel version 2.0.7 in my angular application. I have disabled the default nav text option available because I want to create my custom Prev & Next buttons. Please advise how can i achieve going to the next & prev slide respectively using button clicks. Also, note the application is running in angular.

Here are the buttons with which I want to navigate the carousel.

```
<div class="jo-carousel-custom-nav">
   <button (click)="nextSlide()">previous</button>
   <button (click)="prevSlide()">next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You do know there is a documentation for owl carousel? https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html what exactly is unclear for you there? This page lists all the events you have available.

Comment: I want to implement the same within angular. I tried adding a click event & then calling the next & prev functions but to no avail.

Comment: did you get any errors? Is there an angular version of owl carousel? You don't give us much to work with here. please add enough code so we can reproduce your errors.

Comment: I didn't get any errors. What I want is simple, on the click of any button (Previous or Next), the slides should slide accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I lately found out that the answer to this question is pretty simple. You need to call the previous and next methods to change slides. Have reedited my code block below:

```
<div class="jo-carousel-custom-nav">    
    <button (click)="carousel.previous()">previous</button>    
    <button (click)="carousel.next()">next</button> 
</div>
```